# How to resolve the poppler issue on Mac M1 chip?

Tags: python, apple-m1, poppler, poppler-utils

Unable to import poppler in any environment (python):

```
>>> import poppler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'poppler'
```

Commands ran before this:

1. `brew install cmake`
2. `brew install poppler`
3. Restarted terminal after each step.

Facing a `PoetryException` while adding `python-poppler` as well.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It seems unlikely that adding `cmake` and `poppler` as command-line tools would install anything Python can use. I suspect you'd need a `pip/pip3` command to install some package from https://pypi.org/

Comment: `pip` does not work as well